# When should we use goroutine?

Tags: go, goroutine

When should we use goroutine? I thought we should use it when disk or network I/O to avoid blocking program.

For example, when we want to get some data from Redis.

Without goroutine, we do things in this way:

```golang
res, _ := redis.Get(context.Background(), "test_key").Result()
```

with goroutine, we can do like this:

```
ch := make(chan string)
go func() {
res, _ := redis.Get(context.Background(), "test_key").Result()
ch <- res
}()

res := <-ch
```

I thought this way is better than above. Am I understand it correctly?

Comment: Goroutines serve a different purpose than async/await or promises in JavaScript. In Go you basically **never** need to worry (or even think) about "blocking" vs "non-blocking" operations. Goroutines allow a programming model where you can do things concurrently which is roughly "in parallel".

Answer (score 10):

> I thought this way is better than above. Am i understand correct?

This is incorrect, there is no advantage to to using a goroutine that way. What happens is the current goroutine will start one new goroutine and then block, waiting for the work to finish. This is the same thing that happens without the extra goroutine. The goroutine makes no real difference.

Goroutines are useful when you want to do **multiple** things simultaneously. For example, if you have ten things you want to do at the same time, you can do each one on a separate goroutine, and wait for all of them to finish.

**Note:** You should not be putting `context.Background()` in your functions. Use `context.TODO()` instead. You can put `context.Background()` at the top level.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's really really helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Our friend Dietrich Epp explains very clean and I wanna add something important.

Goroutine makes Go a very strong language, for example, if we compare threads with Goroutins: Goroutines are cheaper than threads, Threads consume a lot of memory due to their large stack size (≥ 1MB). So creating 1000s of threads means you already need 1GB of memory.
But Goroutine created with initial only 2KB of stack size.